# Функция как объект: свой контекст вызова у функции

Tags: javascript

Может ли функция сама для себя быть контекстом вызова (т.е. чтобы `this` функции указывал не на глобальный объект, а на саму функцию)? И если "да", то как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Контекст вызова функции задаётся в месте вызова функции - изнутри функции его не поменять

Comment: интересно какова цель задачи? возможно решения есть в другой плоскости

Answer (score 3):

Реализовать можно через `bind`

> Метод bind() создаёт новую функцию, которая при вызове устанавливает в
> качестве контекста выполнения this предоставленное значение. В метод
> также передаётся набор аргументов, которые будут установлены перед
> переданными в привязанную функцию аргументами при её вызове.

Смотрите `btnfn2` в примере:

```js
function fun() {
  console.log(this.xx)
}
fun.xx = Math.random();
function btnfn1() {
  fun();
}
function btnfn2() {
  const fn = fun.bind(fun);
  fn();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="btnfn1()">btn1</button>
<button onclick="btnfn2()">btn2</button>
```

С тем же эффектом можно вызвать функцию через [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) и [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 2):

Может, вот пример:

```js
function someFunc(){
  console.log( this === someFunc );
}

someFunc.call( someFunc );
```

Ещё пример, где функция сама задаёт свой this, вызывая себя рекурсивно один раз:

```js
function myFunc(){
  // Обеспечиваем this === myFunc
  if( this !== myFunc ) return myFunc.call(myFunc);
  
  // Тут нужные действия пишем...
  console.log('123');
  // ... например проверяем this
  console.log( this === myFunc );
}

myFunc();
```